# update_batch not working at Modal - update function

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter-3, updatebatchsize

In my project we have more than one branch, and they have same Test but, but they have different Price rating. **m_fran_id** is **branch id**, **m_test_id** is the branch **test id** and **m_updated_test_price** is the test Price for specific brunch.

Recommended **update_batch** for **update**  the Branch price. But **update_batch** function is not working.

Table name: fran_test_pricemaster

[image]

Controller

```html
public function masterPrice_update($m_fran_id = null) 
    {
        $data['title'] = display('branch_test_dept_add');

        $sID   = $this->input->post('m_test_id');
        $sAmt  = $this->input->post('m_updated_test_price');
        $sFranId = $this->input->post('m_fran_id');

        $edited_test = array();
        for ($i=0; $i < sizeof($sID); $i++)
        {
            if(!empty($sID[$i])) 
            $edited_test[$i] = array(
                'm_test_id' => $sID[$i],
                'm_updated_test_price' => $sAmt[$i],
                'm_fran_id' => $sFranId

            );
        }
        #-------------------------------#
        if ($this->form_validation->run() === true) {
                    $this->franchise_price_model->singlebatch_Test_updt($edited_test);
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('message', display('save_successfully'));
                    redirect('branch/franchise_price/masterPrice_update');
        } else {
            $data['franceschi_list'] = $this->franceschi_model->franceschi_list();
            $data['test_Masterlist'] = $this->franchise_price_model->readTest_fromMasterPrice($m_fran_id);
            $data['content'] = $this->load->view('branch/fran_pricemasterEdit',$data,true);
            $this->load->view('layout/main_wrapper',$data);
        }
    }
```

Model

```html
public function singlebatch_Test_updt($edited_test = [])
{
    $this->db
    ->update_batch($this->fran_test_pricemaster, $edited_test , 'm_fran_id');
}
```

View

```html
<tbody>
<tr class="<?php echo ($sl & 1)?"odd gradeX":"even gradeC" ?>">
    <td><?php echo $sl; ?></td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="test_name[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $subject->test_name; ?>" disabled>
        <input type="hidden" name="m_test_id[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $subject->m_test_id; ?>">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="test_price[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $subject->test_price; ?>" disabled>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="text" name="m_updated_test_price[]" class="form-control" placeholder="" value="<?php echo $subject->m_updated_test_price; ?>" id="test_priceEdt">
    </td>
</tr>

</tbody>
```

Comment: do you get any error?

Comment: No , error is not showing !

Comment: did you check your logs?

Comment: I checked but , From **LOG** I am not getting any fruitful information .Sir.